# How to check if an element is an empty list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

One of the column in my df stores a list, and some of the raws have empty items in the list. For example:

> []
>
> ["X", "Y"]
>
> []

etc...

How can only take the raw whose list is not empty?

The following code does not work.

```
df[df["col"] != []] # ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
df[pd.notnull(df["col"])] # The code doesn't issue an error but the result includes an empty list
df[len(df["col"]) != 0] # KeyError: True
```

Comment: Will they always be lists or do you need to check if it's a list?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df[df["col"].str.len() != 0]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [[1], [2, 3], [], [4, 5, 6], []]}, dtype=object)
print(df[df["col"].str.len() != 0])
#          col
# 0        [1]
# 1     [2, 3]
# 3  [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: The code works, thanks. But could you give me more explanation, especially why you need `.str` here? It is very unintuitive and near impossible to get to the code, unless you read the official doc from the top to the bottom.

Comment: @Blaszard It is a bit of a "trick". functions under `.str` are meant to be used with string data. They are not really vectorized, it's just application of functions to each data item. In the case of `len`, it just applies the function `len` to each object, so it works fine for strings, lists, or any other object to which `len` can be applied. [Quan Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903992/1782792)'s answer may be more meaningful.

Comment: Agree with jdehesa, this str len method is a good easy trick to remember. But beware of execution times on large dataframes. The Quang Hoang method seems to be vectorized and is MUCH faster.

Answer (score 31):

This is probably the most efficient solution.

```
df[df["col"].astype(bool)]
```

Comment: In Python the most efficient way to check whether a list `l` is empty is to just write `if l: ...`. In other words, `bool(l)` can return a boolean value determining whether a list `l` is empty or not. So it is no wonder that `df["col"].astype("bool")` would also work as expected.

Comment: Efficient in compute terms, or in terms of compactness of code?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
df[df['col'].apply(len).gt(0)]
```

Comment: Although your answer is very succinct, I like it because it's clear it's looking for a list (or string?) and that the length needs to be > 0, so a non-empty list or non-empty string. The problem with the other bool answers is that one needs to know that an empty list evaluates to False (fine), and to figure out that that is the test being applied here (since bool could be testing opaquely for other types). So, nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

#### `bool`

An empty list in a boolean context is `False`.  An empty list is what we call falsey.  It does a programmer well to know what objects are falsey and truthy.

You can also slice a dataframe with a boolean list (not just a boolean series).  And so, I'll use a comprehension to speed up the checking.

```
df[[bool(x) for x in df.col]]
```

Or with even fewer characters

```
df[[*map(bool, df.col)]]
```

Comment: "It does a programmer well to know what objects are falsey and truthy." Reference? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the lists are empty using str.len() and then negate:

```
df[df["col"].str.len() != 0]
...
```

`str.len` is for the Python built-in function returning the length of an object.

And your output should be the expected one.